# Summing the products of multiple variables per row

Tags: r, sum, data.table, rows

I have a data.table as follows:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(panelID = sample(50,50),                                                    # Creates a panel ID
                      Country = c(rep("Albania",30),rep("Belarus",50), rep("Chilipepper",20)),       
                      some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                      some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6),         
                      Group = c(rep(1,20),rep(2,20),rep(3,20),rep(4,20),rep(5,20)),
                      Time = rep(seq(as.Date("2010-01-03"), length=20, by="1 month") - 1,5),
                      norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                      Income = sample(0:5, 6),
                      Happiness = sample(10,10),
                      Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                      Age = sample(100,100),
                      Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))           
DT [, uniqueID := .I]                                                                        # Creates a unique ID     
DT[DT == 0] <- NA                                                                            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036989/replace-all-0-values-to-na
DT$some_NA_factor <- factor(DT$some_NA_factor)
```

Now, I would like to (for some artificial reason) sum the products of income & education and Sex & Age, for each observation using data.table. Please not that my actual data has way more variables, of which some are NA's. I tried:

```
DT<- setDT(DT)[, newvar:= sum((Income *Educ),
   (Sex * Age), na.rm=TRUE)]
```

But that takes the sum of the columns. I also tried:

```
DT<- setDT(DT)[, newvar:= rowSums((Income *Educ),
   (Sex * Age), na.rm=TRUE)]
```

But that does not work:

```
Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

What would be the correct way to do this in data.table?

Comment: When you say "for each observation" you mean for each row ?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31258547/data-table-row-wise-sum-mean-min-max-like-dplyr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DT[, newvar := rowSums(data.table(Income*Educ, Sex * Age), na.rm=TRUE)]

# ALternatively:
DT[, newvar := {x = Income*Educ; y = Sex * Age; fifelse(is.na(x), y, fifelse(is.na(y), x, x + y ))}]
```

Note:

`setDT()` is only necessary if data.frame is not a data.table yet. `<-` (assigning the result is not needed when you use `:=` within the data.table.

Comment: I installed via CRAN few days ago `data.table_1.12.4`. Also see their news (item 21) file on github:  https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md

Comment: see also here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.4/topics/fifelse

Comment: @akrun  maybe try `install.packages('data.table', repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')`

Comment: Ok, thanks, I accidentally used the `no` option earlier to not install from source which is the 1.12.4