# How to apply the function to each row?

Tags: r, data.table

I want to generate 4 new columns from an existing variable `total` by random sampling. the results for each row should meet the condition `s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 == total`.  Fro example,

```
> tabulate(sample.int(4, 100, replace = TRUE))
[1] 22 21 27 30
```

The following code does not work since the function appears to recycle the first row and applies it column-wise.

```
 DT <- data.table(total = c(100, 110, 90, 92))
 DT[, c(paste0("s", 1:4)) := tabulate(sample.int(4, total, replace = TRUE))]

> DT
   total s1 s2 s3 s4
1:   100 31 31 31 31
2:   110 25 25 25 25
3:    90 22 22 22 22
4:    92 22 22 22 22
```

How to get around this? I am clearly missing some basic understanding on how `R` vector/list work.  Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31269167/8245406) can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited following edited question:

`data.table` will expect a list internally when you want to assign to many columns. To get it so each row is unique, then you can do that by adding a `by` each row:

```
DT <- data.table(total = c(100, 110, 90, 102, 92))
DT[, c(paste0("s", 1:4)) := {
  as.list(tabulate(sample.int(4, total, replace = TRUE)))
  }, by = seq(NROW(DT))]
```

Which outputs the following, satisfying the OP criteria:

```
> DT
   total s1 s2 s3 s4
1:   100 27 28 28 17
2:   110 25 23 36 26
3:    90 26 19 26 19
4:   102 28 24 21 29
5:    92 17 27 22 26
> apply(DT[, 2:5],1, sum)
[1] 100 110  90 102  92
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for the `by` tip.   I wonder if the performance can be improved.  I run a test with one million numbers `> DT <-  data.table(total = round(rnorm(1000000, mean = 800, sd = 250)) )
> DT[total < 160, total := 240]` and it take 57 sec on my workstation computer.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get much faster. Just the `sample.int` line takes at least 40 seconds on my machine: `> system.time(vals <- sample.int(4, sum(DT$total), replace = TRUE)) ... 41.11 seconds`

Comment: Yes.  I was thinking alternative to `sample.int` --- it is linearly scaled with `total`

Comment: Apparently, there is: package `dqrng`. Replace the `sample.int` with `dqrng::dqsample.int` and it was over 3x faster for me (~20s), even on the large dataset.

Comment: That settles it for now.  Many thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
DTout <- cbind(
  DT,
  do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(DT$total, function(x) diff(sort(c(0, sample(x - 1, 3), x))))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
   total V1 V2 V3 V4
1:   100 51  5 17 27
2:   110 41  1 40 28
3:    90 32 34 14 10
4:   102  5 73 13 11
5:    92 17 13 17 45
```

**Test**

```
> rowSums(DTout[,-1])
[1] 100 110  90 102  92
```

Comment: @Dong See my test, I didn't see any problem

Comment: I meant your sampling to the four bins are not random.  It is  would be unlikely to hit  a bin only once in 110 random tries as in your row 2.

Comment: @Dong What I sampled is the positions to set bins. Let's say we have 110 balls, and we have 109 possible positions to set 3 barriers, such that we randomly choose 3 positions out of 109 options to produce four partitions. So my method has four random bins.

Comment: My original `sample.int` function intends to randomly distribute 110 balls to four bins with equal probability.